# What is the correct way to shut down a server from the terminal?

Tags: go, network-programming

I am trying my hands on some basic chat (server + client) stuff in Go so I have a server which listens on a specific port and I have a client which writes to this port.

However, as I am new to this, I constantly make changes and have to restart the server etc. I've been doing 'Ctrl + C' everytime I want to stop server but this is obviously stupid as I have to change the port number on every compilation... What is the correct way of doing this? I'm currently just doing

```
defer ln.Close()
```

in the main function of the server after the connection has been established but I guess Ctrl + C just kills the process without closing the connection?

EDIT: More information.
I am running cygwin on Windows. ps shows no old processes but I found a looot of "server.exe" (my server file is named server.go) in the task manager.

Comment: `Ctrl+C` is fine. Why would you have to change the port number?

Comment: Is it really a terminal where you're doing ctrl+c or some sort of IDE? I had trouble with Atom and the most popular app runners there, as killing the process would only kill `go run` and leave the child process running. Make sure your server is killed properly and not running in the background.

Comment: If I don't change the port number I get an error "Error listening: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: bind: normally only one user is allowed. exit status 1".

If I pick a new port number, everything works as expected

Comment: Sounds like you're using windows, so I might not be much help. I do know Windows allows immediately reusing ports by default. Are you certain the old process is actually being shut down on Ctrl+C?

Comment: I'm using cygwin on Windows and when I run `ps` I only have bash and mintty running

Comment: You could use [`signal.Notify`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#Notify) with [`os.Interrupt`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Interrupt) to return from `main` (and let all the defer's run) when you see Ctrl+C. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/_j__5gBpG2 but perhaps with a close on the listen socket too.

Comment: Or perhaps: https://play.golang.org/p/R3e7TW3dPg

Comment: cygwin is likely the problem here (it's not officially supported, since Go runs natively on windows). There's probably some mismatch between Go setting SO_REUSEADDR and how it's translated to windows, since the semantics on each platform are different. I would recommend using Go natively if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using [`os/signal`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) package to Notify you when you hit `Ctrl+C` your defer statement will not get run.

Here is an example of a handled SIGINT (Ctrl+C) to exit a program cleanly.

```
func main() {
    done := make(chan os.Signal)
    go signal.Notify(done, syscall.SIGINT)

    go func() {
         // your tcp server goes here along with the defer to clean up your server
    }()

    <-done

    // exit cleanly
}
```

Comment: All open file descriptors are closed by the OS when a process exits. While the user may want to register a signal handler for other reasons, there's no way for the socket to still be open after the process terminates.

Comment: @JimB Yeah that's what I thought, I don't use Windows but when I googled a bit I saw this answer http://serverfault.com/a/273727 that made me believe that an explicit close would solve the problem and knowing that defer statements don't get run on SIGINT I thought if he handled the signal he could ensure that his server got closed.